# how I pass a dynamic value to use in a v-if in the parent?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I need "showIMP" to be passed to the parent whenever it updates, it updates when the screen width size changes. For some reason @resize="switchShow" is not getting the function, I would also like to know how I could pass this value on to the father, whenever he changes.

If any one can help <3

father

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <Cadastro :caminho="caminho" :nomeEntidade="nomeEntidade"/>
        </div>

        <ValidationObserver ref="observer" v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">  
            <Formulario> 
                <div class="columns is-multiline">
                    <div class="column is-full-mobile is-two-fifth">
                        <VInput rules="required|max:100" type="text" label="Nome" v-model="servidor_smtp.nome"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column is-full-mobile is-one-fifth">
                        <VSelect :itens="[{value:'1', text:'Produção'}, {value:'2', text:'Homologação'}, {value: 3, text:'Desenvolvimento'}]"
                            label="Tipo" itemValue="value" itemText="text" v-model="servidor_smtp.ambiente"/>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="column is-full-mobile is-one-fifth">
                        <VSelect :itens="[{value:'1', text:'Interno'}, {value:'2', text:'Externo'}]"
                            label="Tipo" itemValue="value" itemText="text" v-model="servidor_smtp.tipo"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column is-full-mobile is-narrow">
                        <div class="columns is-multiline">
                            <div class="column is-full-mobile is-narrow">
                                <VSwitch label="Usa TLS?" trueValue="Sim" falseValue="Não" size="is-medium" v-model="servidor_smtp.usar_tls"/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="column is-full-mobile is-narrow">
                                <VSwitch label="Ativo" trueValue="Ativo" falseValue="Inativo" size="is-medium" v-model="servidor_smtp.ativo"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column is-full-mobile is-one-fifth">
                        <VSelect :itens="[{value:'1', text:'Produção'}, {value:'2', text:'Homologação'}, {value: 3, text:'Desenvolvimento'}]"
                            label="Tipo" itemValue="value" itemText="text" v-model="servidor_smtp.ambiente"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column is-full-mobile is-one-fifth">
                        <VSelect :itens="[{value:'1', text:'Interno'}, {value:'2', text:'Externo'}]"
                            label="Tipo" itemValue="value" itemText="text" v-model="servidor_smtp.tipo"/>
                    </div>   

                </div>

                <div class="columns is-multiline">
                    <div class="column is-full-mobile is-one-quarter">
                        <VInput rules="required|max:100" type="text" label="Host" v-model="servidor_smtp.host"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column is-full-mobile is-one-quarter">
                        <VInput rules="required|max:4" type="number" label="Porta" v-model="servidor_smtp.porta"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column is-full-mobile is-one-quarter">
                        <VInput rules="required|max:100" type="text" label="Usuário" v-model="servidor_smtp.usuario"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column is-full-mobile is-one-quarter">
                        <VInput rules="required|max:100" type="password" label="Senha" password-reveal v-model="servidor_smtp.senha"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Formulario>

            <div>
                <CaixaBotoes @salvar="handleSubmit(salvar)" caminhoVoltar="/cadastros/servidor-smtp/listagem"/>
            </div>
        </ValidationObserver>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ValidationObserver } from 'vee-validate'
import Formulario from '~/components/Formulario'
import VSwitch from '~/components/inputs/VSwitch'
import VSelect from '~/components/inputs/VSelect'
import VInput from '~/components/inputs/VInput'
import CaixaBotoes from '~/layouts/CaixaBotoes'
import Cadastro from '~/layouts/Cadastro'
import apiClient from '@/utils/apiClient'
import notification from '@/utils/notification'

export default {
    name: 'CadastroServidorSmtp',

    components: {
        ValidationObserver,
        VInput,
        Formulario,
        VSwitch,
        VSelect,
        Cadastro,
        CaixaBotoes
    },

    // props:{
    //     showIMP:{
    //         type: Boolean
    //     }
    // },

    computed: {
        caminho() {
            return this.$store.state.servidorSmtp.caminho
        }
    },
    
    data() {
        return {
            servidor_smtp: {
                id: this.$route.query.id,
                nome: null,
                ativo: true,
                ambiente: 1,
                tipo: 1,
                host: null,
                porta: null,
                usuario: null,
                senha: null,
                usar_tls: false,
            },
            nomeEntidade: 'Servidor SMTP'
        }
    },

    methods: {
        async salvar() {
            try {
                if (this.servidor_smtp.id) {
                    await apiClient.updateServidorSmtp(this.servidor_smtp)
                } else {
                    await apiClient.createServidorSmtp(this.servidor_smtp)
                }

                this.$router.push({ path: '/cadastros/servidor-smtp/listagem', query: { success: true} })
            } catch (err) {
                notification.sendNotification('Ocorreu um erro ao salvar, tente novamente!', 'is-danger', 5000)
            }
        }
    },

    async created() {
        if(this.servidor_smtp.id) {
            try {    
                this.servidor_smtp = await apiClient.getServidorSmtpById(this.servidor_smtp.id)
            } catch (err) {
                notification.sendNotification('Ocorreu um erro ao buscar, tente novamente!', 'is-danger', 5000)
            } 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

child

```
<template>
    <ValidationProvider
        :vid="vid"
        :rules="rules"
        v-slot="{ errors }">

        <b-field 
            v-bind="$attrs" 
            :type="{ 'is-danger': errors[0] }" 
            :message="errors" @resize="switchShow">
            
            <b-select v-bind="$attrs" v-model="innerValue" expanded>
                <option v-for="item in itens" 
                    :key="getItemValue(item)"
                    :value="getItemValue(item)">
                    {{ getItemText(item) }}
                </option>
            </b-select>
        </b-field>
    </ValidationProvider>
</template>

<script>
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate'

export default {
    components: {
        ValidationProvider,
    },
    
    props: {
        rules: {
            type: [Object, String],
            default: null
        },
        itens: {
            require: true,
            type: Array
        },
        itemValue: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        itemText: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        value: {
            type: null
        },
        vid: {
            default: null
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
        })
    },
    
    beforeDestroy() { 
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize); 
    },

    methods: {
        switchShow: function(event) {
            if (this.windowWidth<=1250){
                this.showIMP = false
            }else{
                this.showIMP = true
            }
            console.log("event")
        },

        onResize() {
            this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth
            console.log("testing")
        },

        getItemValue(option) {
            const property = this.itemValue
            let result = null

            if (option[property] != null) {
                result = option[property]
            } 
            return result
        },
        getItemText(option) {
            const property = this.itemText
            let result = null

            if (option[property] != null) {
                result = option[property]
            } 
            return result
        }
    },

    data() { 
        return {
            innerValue: null,
            windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
            showIMP: true
        }
    },

    watch: {
        innerValue(newVal) {
            this.$emit('input', newVal)
        },

        value(newVal) {
            this.innerValue = newVal
        }
    },

    created() {
        if (this.value) {
            this.innerValue = this.value
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

thank you for the patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emit an event about changing `showIMP`:

```
if (this.windowWidth<=1250){
                this.showIMP = false
            }else{
                this.showIMP = true
            }
this.$emit('onShowIMPChanged', this.showIMP);
```

and catch this event in a parent component:

```
<child @onShowIMPChanged="onShowIMPChanged" ...
...
methods: {
  onShowIMPChanged(showIMP) {
  }
}
```